# "DPRP is disabled for this merchant." on our live mode

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

We are having this error when purchasing using a credit card. "DPRP is disabled for this merchant." on our live mode.

In test mode I dont have any issue using a credit card to purchase.

We tried calling paypal support and they give us paypal manager and told us the DPRP is enabled. But when I did the test it still not working and showing the same error.

Im guessing that DPRP is still not enabled, so we tried calling again to verify regarding the DPRP and support said it enabled, did a test again and its still show the same error!

We are using Paypal Payment PRO and using NVP to communicate with paypal.

Does anyone have an idea or advice on how to fixed this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If this is a Paypal problem only they can help you. If this is a problem with your code you'd need to post some for us to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that DoDirectPayment is not active on the account you're trying to run it from.

Have you applied for Payments Pro and gotten it active on your account?  If so, and you're still getting this message, that means you got the newer version of Pro which works on the PayFlow API instead of DoDirectPayment, so you would need to use that instead.

Comment: Can you give me the link of the PHP PayFlow API code. So i can try the same.

Comment: https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowpro_guide.pdf